# Counting rows of table2 does not include all rows of table1 in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have table 1 that represents Items with column ItemID and column ItemInfo.
Then, I have table 2 that represents SubItems with column ItemID (the parent), column SubItemID and column SubItemInfo.

I'm trying to get the count of all subitems for each item with this :

```
select items.itemID, count(*) as count 
from items, subItems 
where subItems.itemID=items.itemID group by itemID
```

It works fine except for items that don't have sub-items. Instead of returning the item row with a sub-item count of 0, the row is simply not there.

Is there an efficient way to force all rows from the first table (Items) to be selected ?

Comment: It actually works with LEFT OUTER JOIN but is much slower and I'm not sure why...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You neet to use left outer join, than you'll get 0 for items having no subitems, like that:

```
SELECT items.itemid,
       Count(subitems.subitemid) AS count
FROM   items
       LEFT JOIN subitems
              ON ( subitems.itemid = items.itemid )
GROUP  BY items.itemid
```

If you wanted to have better performance, you could try this query:

```
SELECT itemid,
       Count(*) AS count
FROM   subitems
GROUP  BY itemid
```

BUT, with this one you will not get any info about the items, that have no subitems (they are simply not present within subitems table).

Comment: I've noticed that it does what I want with LEFT JOIN but is a lot slower. Is this normal ? That's why I posted the question in case there was a more efficient solution.

Comment: Do you have an indexes on `subitems.itemid` and `items.itemid` columns?

Comment: Wow ! That was it ! Indexes were not there for subitems.itemid ! Thanks a lot WojtusJ !!!

Comment: No problem, always look at the execution plan, it's easy, and with some simple knowledge you will be able to improve you queries signifincantly. It's also a good practise to place your execution plan along with your question (if you ask about performance), it will be easier for people to identify the problem.

Comment: Will sure do ! Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

```
select items.itemID, count(*) as count 
  from items
  left join subItems on (items.itemID=subItems.itemID) 
group by itemID
```